# Is it necessary to chant the name of god in the multiples of 108?

Tags: bhakti

Why do many people keep mala having 108 beads to chant the name of god ?
Can't they just keep chanting the name of god without keeping a count on it ?

Is it necessary to chat the name of god in the multiple of 108 ?